# Book on vainayiki vidya?

Tags: book-recommendation

Reference material or book on Vainayiki vidya - enforcing discipline.

or Is there any book where I can study 64 Arts / 14 Vidyas.

Comment: A wise man once told in a meeting that if we closely follow the character of Sri Hanuman in Valmiki Ramayana, you will learn the art of communication, art of being self-disciplined, etc, @HinduKid